# AttributeError: type object 'Car' has no attribute 'speed'

Tags: python

i got the error message when i am calling Car class with object car

```
class Car:
def __init__(self, speed, unit):
    self.speed = speed
    self.unit = unit
def __new__(self, speed, unit):
    str = "Car with the maximum speed of {} {}".format(self.speed, self.unit)
    return str
```

Comment: i want to return the str just by calling the object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**new** is the first step of instance creation. **It's called first**, and is responsible for returning a new instance of your class.

In contrast, **init** doesn't return anything; it's only responsible for initializing the instance after it's been created.

```
class Car:
    # def __init__(self, speed, unit):
    #     self.speed = speed
    #     self.unit = unit
    def __new__(self, speed, unit):
        self.speed = speed
        self.unit = unit
        str = "Car with the maximum speed of {} {}".format(self.speed, self.unit)
        return str

a = Car(10, 2)
print(a)
```

```
Car with the maximum speed of 10 2
```

*In general, you shouldn't need to override **new** unless you're subclassing an immutable type like str, int, unicode or tuple.*

ANOTHER WAY

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, speed, unit):
        self.speed = speed
        self.unit = unit
    def __str__(self):
        str = "Car with the maximum speed of {} {}".format(self.speed, self.unit)
        return str

a = Car(10, 2)
print(a)
```

```
Car with the maximum speed of 10 2
```

Comment: @VivekGautam I am glad it helped, if your query is resolved please mark it as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the indentation and using a method `speed_check()` along with a single constructor:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, speed, unit):
        self.speed = speed
        self.unit = unit
    def speed_check(self):
        return "Car with the maximum speed of {} and the unit {}".format(self.speed, self.unit)
        
CarObj = Car(120, 10)
result = CarObj.speed_check()

print(result)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Car with the maximum speed of 120 and the unit 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `__new__` and i can't tell why. You can use this instead:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, speed, unit):
        self.speed = speed
        self.unit = unit
    def new(self):
        str = "Car with the maximum speed of {} {}".format(self.speed, self.unit)
        return str
```